# Get proportional gray colors using a custom color in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I need get the proportional gray colors using a custom color and keep the default percentages using LESS. These are the bootstrap's defaults:

```
@gray-darker:            lighten(#000, 13.5%); // #222
@gray-dark:              lighten(#000, 20%);   // #333
@gray:                   lighten(#000, 33.5%); // #555
@gray-light:             lighten(#000, 46.7%); // #777
@gray-lighter:           lighten(#000, 93.5%); // #eee
```

How can I change these colors using for instance #173B52?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was easy:

```
@gray-darker:            screen(lighten(#000, 13.5%), #173B52);
@gray-dark:              screen(lighten(#000, 20%),   #173B52);
@gray:                   screen(lighten(#000, 33.5%), #173B52);
@gray-light:             screen(lighten(#000, 46.7%), #173B52);
@gray-lighter:           screen(lighten(#000, 93.5%), #173B52);
```

More info: http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-blending-screen

Comment: `overlay` would probably be better. `screen` will work only to lighten dark colors while `overlay` can produce suitable results for any. And btw., you don't even need *two* functions there. Just `overlay(#fff * .135, #173B52);`, `overlay(#fff * .2, #173B52);` etc. should do the trick. [E.g.](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/yozvw)).

Comment: But `overlay` is not working very well in this case, because actually I don't get the proportional values. Further, we talking about gray colors and we don't need light colors. Nice trick by the way!

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood your intentions (w/o seeing the actual colors your method produce). Then yes, `screen(#fff * .135, #173B52);` would be equal ([codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/foFyG)).